# Why is silicone caulk still wet to the touch a day later?

Tags: silicone

I have a glass & metal umbrella table that needed to have the metal frame glued to the underside of the glass. I flipped the glass table upside down on another table. I clamped the corners down and applied the GE silicone. I went to Home Depot and bought two more tubes.  It is now twenty-four hours later, and it is still wet to touch.  Where do I go from here?  If it never sets up, then I cannot apply the next layer.  With uncured silicone residue and re-apply because it will not adhere.  What to do now?

Comment: Or this? [Thorough removal of uncured silicone sealant](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/204448/thorough-removal-of-uncured-silicone-sealant)

Comment: Or this? [Does washroom silicone caulk turn into goo after time?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/165332/does-washroom-silicone-caulk-turn-into-goo-after-time)

Comment: How old is your caulk?  Was the tube you applied opened previously?

Answer (score 3):

If it smells weird and never sets up, it's too old. The only way to fix things is to clean it up with acetone or mineral spirits and start fresh with a tube that is within expiration. If you bought the tubes recently and they were already expired, bring them back and exchange them at the home store.